# Retrieving all Keywords based on Category WebDAV using CoreService in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, core-service, taxonomy, keyword

For cache purpose we're querying some Keywords based on Category WebDAV on application start. In Tridion 2011 following code used to achive this and worked well:

```cs
_coreService.GetSearchResults(new SearchQueryData { 
      ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Keyword },
      SearchIn = new LinkToIdentifiableObjectData { WebDavUrl = categoryWebDav } })
  .Select(k => k as KeywordData).ToArray();
```

However when we upgraded our Tridion 2011 to Tridion 2011 SP1 that piece of code doesn't work anymore and returns empty array for some reason.

So, is there way to fix this method to make it works as before or maybe there are some alternative way getting this? Please note that only `IdentifiableObjectData` array as return value is applicable.

Comment: Does search work at all? Can you find items that were created before update? I believe all you need to do is to reindex the search database

Comment: Also, why do you use search instead of doing GetList on category?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Search doesn't work well even in Tridion CMS. Unfortunately we don't have access to tridion server and guys who support it said that they reindexed cm database, but it didn't help.

Comment: Regarding second comment, I tried something like that: `core.GetList(categoryTcm, new KeywordsFilterData())`, but it returns an exception: _Unexpected list type: Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ContentManagement.KeywordsFilterData._. However, GetListXml works well

Comment: The exception you mention was thrown on 2011, on 2013SP1 it will work fine

Comment: Did you 2013 SP1 or 2011 SP1? Because we're using 2011 SP1

Comment: My bad, in 2011 SP1 it will not work, only GetListXml

Answer (score 1):

Does search work at all? Can you find items that were created before update? I believe all you need to do is to reindex the search database.

On a separate note, it's better to do GetList on category, instead of using search.